# Get the previous of the previous url in classic ASP

Tags: php, iframe, asp-classic, http-referer

I've got a classic ASP page into an iframe of a PHP page.

If I use:

```
Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER");
```

I get the URL of the wrapper PHP page.

I would like to get the previous PHP page of the wrapper page.

Is this possible?

Comment: does ASP and PHP running on the same web server? under the same application pool?

Comment: they are on the same domain, but I don't think that they use the same application pool

Comment: anyway, afaik you could get only 1 last referer page. may be you should create your own array/dictionary in Session object and keep list of last N referer pages?